# How can I save the new order of a re-orderable list?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm on an apprenticeship and my boss gave me the challenge of making a list re-orderable.

Using Jquery UI Ive added the drag and drop functionality and I've added a label to show the index of each item.

The problem is I can't seem to get it to save the new order back to the database.

**Here's the repeater...**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterWorkOrder" runat="server" OnLoad="Repeater1_PreRender" DataSourceID="sqlwork">
   <HeaderTemplate>                  
      <ul id="headingRow" style="list-style-type:none; font-weight:bold;">
         <li>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-3">Name</div>
               <div class="col-xs-3">Address</div>
               <div class="col-xs-2">Service</div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">Van</div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">Remaining Visits</div>
               <div class="col-xs-2">Order of Work</div>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sortable">
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="ui-state-default" style="list-style-type:none; margin-top: 10px;" >
         <div class="row">                                                                                                            
            <div class="col-xs-3"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' Visible="true"/> - <asp:Label ID="LabelWorkSheetId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("WorkItemId") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label> <asp:Label ID="LabelFirstNameEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LabelSurnameEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Surname") %>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"><asp:Label ID="LabelAddressLine1Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("AddressLine1") %>'></asp:Label>, <asp:Label ID="LabelTownEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Town") %>'></asp:Label>, <asp:Label ID="LabelPostCodeEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("PostCode") %>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"><asp:Label ID="LabelServiceEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Service") %>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"><asp:Label ID="LabelVanEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("VanRegistration") %>'></asp:Label></div>                                                
            <div class="col-xs-1"><asp:Label ID="LabelRemainingVisits" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("RemainingVisits") %>'></asp:Label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-2"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("DayWorkOrder") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox></div>
        </div>
     </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      </ul>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And this is the Jquery UI script

```
<script>
    function BindControlEvents() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection(); 
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindControlEvents();
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
       BindControlEvents();
    });
</script>
```

When I load the web page I get a list of items and using;

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' Visible="true"/>
```

They each have an index number so the list appears like...

1

2

3

I then reorder the list to

2

1

3

but when I refresh the page, it loads the original order again.

I think when I move something, I need to then have a script that changes the index number of that item, and therefore all the others?

Comment: Ajax can be help here. Jquery ui has mechanism to generate a event when the reordering is finished. In this event you can write a ajax function which will send the reordered index and send this data to server. On server side you've to save it. so when reloading read the order which you've saved and display accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You need to post back your sorted data from view back to the server, for example by adding a "Save" button. In that button onClick event you should get items from repeater and save your re-ordered items back to database, so when the page loads again, your repeater will be populated with sorted data. 
Here's some code you can use to retrieve data from repeater:

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterWorkOrder.Items){
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
                // Here you can get values from each repeater item
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some factor need think, over these your can do it.

**Do your data's sort-number is controlled, and are they need pagination?**
I don't know how much data in you this page. If the data just list for one page and there are not much data in this page. You can use a simple method to reorder all data.

But if there are very much data in list and there are some page in pagination, then you need a complex method to reorder these data. And a important factor is do the sort-number in your data can repeat? If can repeat sort-number, maybe there are some bug in this reorder method.

I create a WebFrom call Resort.aspx. This code supposed the sort-number of data is auto create by program, and the sort-number is sole.

This is a simple code for you for reference, the theory of this code:

1. After re-sort, post all data-item's id and page-index to a back-end URL by AJAX;
2. Back-end method get data-id and page-index, calculate the new sort-number for every date-item;
3. Save new sort-number to database.

this is `Resort.aspx` source code:

```html
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="Resort.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Resort" %>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .box {
                border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
            }
    
            .move {
                cursor: move;
            }
    
            .box li:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) !important;
            }
    
            #sortable {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 10px;
                width: 450px;
                border: 3px dotted #fff;
                padding: 10px;
            }
    
                #sortable li {
                    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
                    padding: 5px;
                    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
                    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
                    font-size: 12px;
                }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var page = "<%=page%>";
              $('.re-sort-btn').on("click", function (ev) {
                  ev.preventDefault();
                  var is_sortable = $("#sortable").sortable('instance');
                  $("#sortable").toggleClass("box");
                  $("#sortable li").toggleClass("move");
                  if (!is_sortable) {
                      $(this).text("Finish & Save!");
                      $("#sortable").sortable({
                          stop: function (event, ui) {
                              $("#sortable").attr("data-changed", true);
                          }
                      });
                      $("#sortable").disableSelection();
                  }
                  else {
                      $(this).text("Re-Sort");
                      $("#sortable").sortable('destroy');
    
                      if ($("#sortable").attr("data-changed")) {
                          var ids = [];
                          $("#sortable li").each(function (index, element) {
                              var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                              ids.push(id);
                          });
                          console.log(ids);
                          $.ajax({
                              url: '?action=reorder',
                              type: 'POST',
                              async: true,
                              data: {
                                  ids: ids.join(","), page: page
                              },
                              timeout: 5000,
                              dataType: 'json',
                              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                  console.log(data);
                                  if (data["status"] === "ok") {
                                      var txt = [];
                                      for (var x in data["sorts"]) {
                                          var t = data["sorts"][x];
                                          for (var k in t)
                                              txt.push(k + " : " + t[k]);
                                      }
                                      alert("new sort : \n" + txt.join("\n"));
                                  }
                                  else
                                      alert("re sort error");
                              },
                              error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                                  console.log('error');
                                  console.log(xhr);
                                  console.log(textStatus);
                              }
                          });
                      }
                  }
              });
          });
        </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
    
                <button class="re-sort-btn">Re-Sort</button>
    
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ul id="sortable">
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li data-id="<%# ((WebApplication1.Test)Container.DataItem).Id %>"><%# String.Format("{0}-{1} ::: old order is {2}",((WebApplication1.Test)Container.DataItem).Id, ((WebApplication1.Test)Container.DataItem).Name, ((WebApplication1.Test)Container.DataItem).Order) %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <%for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
                    {%>
                <a href="?page=<%=i %>"><%=i %></a>
                <%} %>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is `Resort.aspx.cs` source code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Resort : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public int page = 0;
        //datasource, you should access it from database.
        private List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["action"] == "reorder")
            {
                ReOrder();
            }
            else
            {
                page = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["page"] ?? "1");
                int i = 0, page_size = 20, max_page = 9;
                while (i++ < page_size)
                    test.Add(new Test()
                    {
                        Id = (page - 1) * page_size + i,
                        Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                        Order = (max_page + 1) * page_size - page * page_size - i + 1,
                    });

                repeater1.DataSource = test;
                repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is reorder method, response ajax request.
        /// If no pagination, easy more.
        /// </summary>
        protected void ReOrder()
        {
            int page = Convert.ToInt32(Request["page"] ?? "1");
            int page_size = 20; // the number of one page show data
            string[] ids = (Request["ids"] ?? "").Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int max_page = 9; // max page of the data list
            int i = 0;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("{\"status\":\"ok\", \"sorts\":[ ");
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                //below line code is calculate every data's order in now page
                var sort_number = (max_page + 1) * page_size - page * page_size - i++;
                sb.Append("{");
                sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\":{1}", id, sort_number);
                sb.Append("},");
            }
            //save new sort-number to database
            sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            sb.Append("]}");
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// test class just for demo
    /// </summary>
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }

    }
}
```